# what are the whatsapp port numbers?

Tags: iptables, squid

Update question about whatsapp ports:

According to [official facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/):

```
5222
443
```

According to [screwloose](http://www.screwloose.com.au/whatsapp-firewall-ports):

```
TCP: 4244,5222,5223,5228,5242
TCP/UDP: 50318,59234
UDP: 3478,45395
```

According to [quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-port-number-for-whatsapp):

```
TCP Ports; 80, 443, 4244, 5222, 5223, 5228, 5242, 50318, 59234
UDP Ports: 3478, 45395, 50318, 59234
```

According to [user github](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/issues/358#issuecomment-152340366):

```
TCP = 80, 443, 4244, 5060, 5061, 5222, 5223, 5228, 5282
UDP = 5060-5061, 5242, 9785, 40000-60000
```

According to [netify](https://www.netify.ai/resources/protocols/whatsapp-video):

```
TCP 5349
UDP 3478
```

According to "someone on the internet":

```
TCP 4244:5242
```

as I see it, there is no unification of criteria.

**Question:** What are the real TCP/UDP ports used by WhatsApp (sending/receiving messages and voice/video calls)

Comment: Again, what are you talking about? I never said I disliked your firewall rules. I certainly did not say you should remove them. You can read what I actually said above. I asked you for _more_ information, not _less_, and you inexplicably started removing relevant information from your post and leaving irrelevant information up.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, you did it. You called my rules "bizarre". But I am not offended by that. I just want my question to be clear, that's why I deleted them

Comment: What is your real question, then? If you don't want to get whatsapp working, why even mention that it is blocked? You can delete that too, because it is also irrelevant.

Comment: Run whatsapp and do a tcpdump to analyze outbound traffic and analyze it, you will see the ports it uses.

Answer (score 4):

Squid is a proxy, not a firewall.

Even if you *could* proxy non-web traffic through Squid, there is no way to tell WhatsApp to use your proxy.

You need to allow that traffic through your firewall.

Comment: The firewall is supposed to send the traffic to the squid port. That is not my question. My question is what are the whatsapp ports

Comment: You can't use Squid to proxy non-web protocols. As long as WhatsApp is sending HTTP/HTTPS requests, they can be made to work through Squid (if it's configured in transparent mode and doesn't require authentication). But everything else will just not work.

Comment: @ajcg I thought your question was: Why is whatsapp blocked? But you deleted everything relevant to that from your question and left in all this irrelevant squid stuff.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please. My question is what are the whatsapp ports (TCP/UDP), the rest is irrelevant

Comment: @ajcg You already know the port numbers!

Answer (score 3):

I use a transparent proxy .. which blocked my whatsapp calls ... the problem was solved by releasing the UDP / 3478 port in the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Set Up and Debug Your Network
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/network-requirements/

this the official doc for network requirements
probably that will put you on the right track
jh

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

In addition that link was already included as the first reference in the original question .